# Post type index as Wordpress front page

Tags: wordpress

How can I submit the index page of a post type as the front page of Wordpress? In the settings, Wordpress only permits pages to be the front page.

```
Example:
Post type: Book
Post type slug: books
Post type index: archieve-books.php
```

I need mydomain.com/books to be called as the front page of mydomain.com
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify for me.. you want to show paginated posts, from your custom post type book, in the front page? Would you be comfortable editing the template files?

Answer (score 0):

This can be very easily done with a custom page.php template. By default, you cannot set an archive page as a front page, you can only set page templates

For reference, see ['Creating a Static Front Page'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

To create a custom front page, copy your page.php template and rename it *front-page.php* Just after the page loop, add a custom query to call your custom post type

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'books',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );

} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

You can now just choose this page as your static front page.